# General approach of left side menu that loads different content in a center of the page

Tags: angularjs

I've started to learn AngularJS but I need some application design hints. Of course I'm not asking about the layout but ... how to design my application and it's controllers in a proper way. I have left sidebar with a menu that is loaded from the web using JSON. That needs a controller. That's fine. It works for me. There's a content box as well in a center of my page that loads some data dynamically. In my opinion it requires another controller.

And now comes my solution, that somehow doesn't look good IMHO. When I click a menu item in my sidebar I'm loading a content. Then I'm passing this data into a Service which emits an Event afterwards to the Second controller (which is responsible for controlling my content in a center of my page). When it receives this event it simply gets previously loaded data from the Service and displays it. It generally works.... but ... I'm pretty sure that's not the proper way of doing this.

I would be grateful for any hints. AngularJS has a really poor documentation and tutorial :(

cheers

EDIT:

OK. That's my basic application using JQuery:

http://greatanubis-motoscore.rhcloud.com/index

And that's the same application I'm converting into AngularJS:

http://greatanubis-motoscore.rhcloud.com/angular/index

No worries, some text is in Polish but... I think it really doesn't matter ;)

Note for the AngularJS version: At the moment the content is a HTML but finally it will load JSON data as the other controllers.

Comment: If you could post a sample of your code to plunker, it would help a lot. Otherwise it's difficult to provide constructive criticism.

Comment: You mean something like angular-ui-router, ngRoute (`ng-view`), or `ng-include` ?

Comment: OK. I've updated my question. Now you can look into my implementation.

Comment: Did you try looking at the tabs example on angular home page? https://angularjs.org/ (look for "Create components") I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you mean under "ng-conf 2014"? Well.. as I see it uses only one controller that stands on the top. I have a sidebar. I should have something like a global controller to manage my sidebar menu AND the content, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go about doing this with angular [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). With ui-router you can achieve this in a couple of ways. You can use nested routing to have a base state (Your sidebar menu, header etc.) which will act as your shell page, this can have its own controller as well. You could then define each of those other views as child states of the base state. These child states can also have their own controller/views as well, but they will be sitting inside the base state (both visually, and also inherit `$scope` properties of the base state) optionally they can have separated URLs themselves, but they don't have to, you can just change states without changing the url, by leaving the URL bit empty when you define different states in your `$stateProvider` configs. Another way would be to use the [multiple named views feature](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. I'll play with that a bit before I accept your answer :) I hope you're OK with that. cheers

Comment: No problem, I'll see if i can get a demo plunk up for you.

Comment: Really? That would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That's an Amazing example. Thank you!